# Bifurcations in flows on 2-dimensional torus

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, difference-equations

I am doing research on bifurcations which appear in flows on the 
2-dimensional torus, in particular on such which do not appear in flows
on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Can anyone provide some references on this?
-- I did not find good references so far.